# Subclassing a UIView, one method to setup whether initWithFrame: or awakeFromNib

Tags: uiview, initialization, subclassing

When subclassing a UIView I tend to create a private method called 'setup', which I put into `initWithFrame` and `awakeFromNib`.

Is this what other people tend to do too? Or is there a method I don't know about that does what I'm looking to do.

I've been through the `UIView` class reference but I can't see anything, so just wondered what others do?

Answer (score 0):

I actually avoid using `-awakeFromNib` and use `-initWithCoder:` instead. This is my typical UIView subclass setup:

```c
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self _init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self _init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self _init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)_init {

}
```

I actually have a Snippet to do this too. I just type

```
init_view
```

And it generates all of the above.